# Why when a jquery draggable element is removed, I get a wrong count?

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

I have encountered an unexpected behaviour that occurs when a jquery draggable element is removed. If I do not set a setTimeout then the count of the remaining elements is wrong.

Could someone explain me why I need this delay ?

```
$("#mytable tr").draggable({ helper: "clone"});

$('#trash').droppable({
    tolerance: "pointer",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.draggable.remove();

        alert($('#mytable tr').length);
        // --> this gives a wrong number of rows

        //setTimeout(function(){alert($('#mytable tr').length);},0);
        // --> this gives the right number despite the 0 delay
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PBrockmann/ewgevoc5/

Answer (score 1):

Your alert is counting the clone that the draggable item creates when you drag it with your mouse (if you inspect the DOM tree, you can see the new `<tr>` element is created as a child of the `<table>` element).

By calling the setTimeout function, it essentially moves the alert to the end of the call stack, which allows the jQuery code to clean up the clone before the alert is called.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. Can I do a better way ?

Comment: You should be able to call ui.helper.remove(); under the ui.draggable.remove(); to remove the clone as well.

Comment: Thks. Indeed You must remove the clone. Now works with logic.